# Setup Nginx + Passenger with Rails App and Vue.js app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, vue.js, passenger

I have an Nginx remote server with Passenger that serves my Rails API over a public IP 12.34.56.78.

Now, I have deployed a Vue.js app to the same host and am able to access the app from the browser by putting in the IP address 12.34.56.78 but when I try to sign in I get and error `CONNECTION REFUSED`

This is my `nginx.conf`

#### Rails app

```
server {
    listen       3000;
    server_name  bikeramp.local;

    root /home/deploy/bikeramp/current/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env production;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/bikeramp.access.log;
    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

#### Vue.js app

```
server {
        listen   80 default_server;
        server_name  bikeramp_front.local;

        location / {
            root   /home/jdomanski/bikeramp-front;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
```

I have confirmed both my apps are being served by Nginx:

```
netstat -tln

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41382         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50022           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

I am able to access my Vue.js app from the IP address 12.34.56.78/signin but when I make a HTTP request from the front-end sign in form I get an error

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:3000/api/users/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

This is the code where I make the HTTP request to the API

`axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000'`

When I make the request from front-end on my local machine by pointing to the remote IP I now get an error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://54.38.36.242/api/users/login. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.`

How can I configure Nginx to make requests from my front end app to the backend app living on the same host served by the same Nginx server. I am probably lacking something in my `nginx.conf` file. Can you help me? Should I enable CORS in Nginx?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're serving the frontend from a different domain, so, yes you need CORS with permissive `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` (either `*` or the domains you are using in dev).

Edit: you can use NGINX for this, or Rails (for example https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors)

Comment: But why am I getting `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSE`? Is it really related to CORS? It looks like it didn't udnerstand the address or something.

Comment: I have updated my question. Is it because the server is not configured to accept OPTIONS request? I am doing POST request so it might not be passing OPTIONS

Comment: I have configured by Rails app with CORS as per the docs you provided but that didn't work.

Comment: which server block do I need to configure with CORS? the rails app server block or vuejs app server block? I have tried both and no luck

Comment: If you are getting `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSE` that means the port is not open, which is weird if the result of `netstat` is correct and up-to-date. See if the port is accessible with either `telnet localhost 3000` or `curl`.

Comment: The Rails app (the API) will need CORS headers. According to the error message you posted though, it is trying to connect to `54.38.36.242`, not to localhost.

Comment: Wait I think I see the problem now  - you have deployed the frontend to some URL but it still tries to acces the backend via localhost:3000. You should use the real IP of the backend (if you haven't configure host names)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184488/discussion-between-mihai-tarnovan-and-jedi).